# How to get odds-ratios and other related features with scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm going through this [odds ratios in logistic regression tutorial](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stata/faq/how-do-i-interpret-odds-ratios-in-logistic-regression/), and trying to get the exactly the same results with the logistic regression module of scikit-learn. With the code below, I am able to get the coefficient and intercept but I could not find a way to find other properties of the model listed in the tutorial such as *log-likelyhood, Odds Ratio, Std. Err., z, P>|z|, [95% Conf. Interval]*. If someone could show me how to have them calculated with `sklearn` package, I would appreciate it.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

url = 'https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/sample.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(url, na_values=[''])
y = df.hon.values
X = df.math.values
y = y.reshape(200,1)
X = X.reshape(200,1)
clf = LogisticRegression(C=1e5)
clf.fit(X,y)
clf.coef_
clf.intercept_
```

Comment: fyi you should do the import as `from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression`

Comment: when I run this code I get `databricks/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py:760: DataConversionWarning: A column-vector y was passed when a 1d array was expected. Please change the shape of y to (n_samples, ), for example using ravel().
  y = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)
Out[2]: LogisticRegression(C=100000.0, class_weight=None, dual=False,
                   fit_intercept=True, intercept_scaling=1, l1_ratio=None,                   max_iter=100, multi_class='auto', n_jobs=None, penalty='l2', random_state=None, solver='lbfgs', tol=0.0001, verbose=0,warm_start=False)`

Comment: I am pretty sure I had been using Python 2.7 by the time I had run into this issue.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can get the odds ratios by taking the exponent of the coeffecients:

```
import numpy as np
X = df.female.values.reshape(200,1)
clf.fit(X,y)
np.exp(clf.coef_)

# array([[ 1.80891307]])
```

As for the other statistics, these are not easy to get from scikit-learn (where model evaluation is mostly done using cross-validation), if you need them you're better off using a different library such as [statsmodels](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/index.html).

Comment: Thanks @maxymoo. Yes, I could get other summaries with `statsmodels`.

Comment: Are these values only odds ratios if and only if the features are independent? (i.e. there is no interaction between the features).

Comment: @user48956 take a look at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/57031/interpreting-interaction-terms-in-logit-regression-with-categorical-variables for a good example of how to interpret odds ratios

Answer (score 7):

In addition to @maxymoo's answer, to get other statistics, `statsmodel` can be used. Assuming that you have your data in a `DataFrame` called `df`, the code below should show a good summary:

```
import pandas as pd
from patsy import dmatrices
import statsmodels.api as sm 

y, X = dmatrices( 'label ~ age + gender', data=df, return_type='dataframe')
mod = sm.Logit(y, X)
res = mod.fit()
print res.summary()
```

Answer (score 5):

I don't know such a method using scikit-learn, but [**Table2x2**](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.stats.contingency_tables.Table2x2.html) from statsmodels.api.stats could be useful in your case, as it provides you with the OR, SE, CI and P value with 3 lines of codes:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
table = sm.stats.Table2x2(np.array([[73, 756], [14, 826]]))
table.summary(method='normal')
"""
               Estimate    SE   LCB    UCB p-value
Odds ratio        5.697       3.189 10.178   0.000
Log odds ratio    1.740 0.296 1.160  2.320   0.000
Risk ratio        5.283       3.007  9.284   0.000
Log risk ratio    1.665 0.288 1.101  2.228   0.000
"""
```